# how to create a django form with names from the database

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a sidebar with a drop-down menu that has categories and dishes. I want to create a checkbox for selection dishes

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Dish(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=Category, related_name="children", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    weight = models.IntegerField()
    cost = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Basket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(to=Dish, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)
    created_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Dishes: {self.dish.name} | Manager: {self.user.name}'
```

in html format it looks like this:

```
<div class="filter-content collapse show" id="collapse_1" style="">
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
        {% if category %}
        {% for cat in category %}
        <li class="mb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed"         data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#{{ cat.id }}" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ cat.name }}
            </button>
            {% for dish in cat.children.all %}

            <div class="collapse" id="{{ cat.id }}" style="">
                <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                    <li>
                        <div class="list-group list-group-checkable d-grid gap-2 border-0">
                            <input class="list-group-item-check pe-none" type="checkbox" name="listGroupCheckableRadios" id="{{dish.name}}" value="">
                            <label class="list-group-item rounded-3 py-3" for="{{dish.name}}">
                            {{dish.name}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <p>no values</p>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

to handle clicking on the checkbox, I create a form:

```
class DishForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Basket
        fields = ['dish']
        widgets = {"dish": CheckboxInput(attrs={
            'class': 'list-group-item-check pe-none',
            'type': 'checkbox',
            })
        }
```

and added this form to html

```
<div class="filter-content collapse show" id="collapse_1" style="">
    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
        {% if category %}
        {% for cat in category %}
        <li class="mb-1">
            <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed"         data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#{{ cat.id }}" aria-expanded="false">
                {{ cat.name }}
            </button>
            {% for dish in cat.children.all %}

            <div class="collapse" id="{{ cat.id }}" style="">
                <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                    <li>
                        <form method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="list-group list-group-checkable d-grid gap-2 border-0">
                            {{ form.dish }}
                            <label class="list-group-item rounded-3 py-3" for="{{dish.name}}">
                                {{dish.name}}
                            </label>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        <p>no values</p>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

but I don't understand how to pass the dish name to the form to link it to the label

Answer (score 0):

First of you want to create a `Basket`, not a `Dish`. So rename it as `BasketForm` instead of `DishForm`.
To select one model out of multiple already existing models you want to utilize the [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

Since you said you want to have checkboxes you should change the default [`Select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#select)widget to [`RadioSelect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect).

```py
class BasketForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Basket
        fields = ['dish']
        widgets = forms.ModelChoiceField(
                queryset=Dish.objects.all(), 
                widget=forms.RadioSelect
        )
```

The default template for a form should be enough then. This displays a radiobuttons (checkboxes) where you can select one out of all the `Dish`objects.

```html
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

To define the queryset within the form already is somewhat static. In case you want to have a different selection range for `Dish`es for different views or users or whatever you would want to modify it via the `__init__()` method of the form.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try your way.
But I need a checkbox so that I can put several dishes in the basket at the same time.

Comment: That is not possible. Then you set up the `ForeingKey` the wrong way. Right now a specific `Basket` can be linked to one specific `Dish`. Therefore one specific `Dish` can be linked to a set of `Basket`s. Having set that: If you want to get the functionality to select multiple objects then go for [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) instead of `ModelChoiceField`.

Comment: I thought it was possible to set an event on the checkbox: check-on - add a dish to the basket, check-off - remove a dish from the basket

Comment: Django is the backend of your application. It can only "do stuff" if you send a request, aka reload or load a site. If you want to have events as soon as someone clicks an element on the site you need to go for javascript or any other language that run localy in the browser of the user. My answer with `ModelMultipleChoiceField` does exactly what you are trying to do but only if you submit the form, meaning giving django the chance to "do stuff". Also: with your current model setup **one basket** can only hold **one dish**

Answer (score 0):

`<form method="post">` and `{{ form.dish }}` are overlapping. You have a form inside another form basically.
The rendered version is going to look something like this:

```
<form method="post">
...
     <form method="post">
     </form>
...
</form>
```

And anyway i dont think this is the correct approach. Consider that you can only submit one form at any one time. So you should problably have a parent form and then render the fields. You can do that manually:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for dish in dishes %}
        <label for="{{ dish.id }}">{{ dish.name|title }}</label>
        <input type="check" name="{{ dish.name }}" id="{{ dish.id }}" />
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. But apparently I'm a pretty stupid person. My problem is solved not by a form, but by a button. If you click on the button the dish is added and if the dish is already in the basket - it is deleted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).